# Reuse existing components on the <component> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue template like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component v-for="item in contents" :key="item.id" :is="item.component" v-bind="item.parameters">
    </component>
  </div>
</template>
```

Where someone gives me the contents with a series of things to be displayed:

```
contents: [
  {
    id: "input-222",
    component: 'my-component',
    parameters: {'label': 'World'}
  },
  {
    id: "input-111",
    component: 'v-text-field',
    parameters: {'label': 'Hello', clearable: true}
  }
]
```

but I can't make it work with preexisting components, such as the `v-text-field` from vuetify unless I manually define these components again such as:

```
import VTextField from "vuetify/lib/components/VTextField";
import VTextarea from "vuetify/lib/components/VTextarea";
```

and

```
components: {
  'my-component': MyComponent,
  'v-text-field': VTextField,
  'v-textarea': VTextarea
}
```

So the question is, how can I avoid importing each and every vuetify component I need since if I type `<v-text-field>` inside the template directly it does work?

**THE ERROR I'VE GOT:**

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-textarea> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

---

This is my `main.js`  file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),

  data: {
    products: []
  },

  vuetify,

  mounted () {
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is plugins/vuetify

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});
```

Inside App.vue I have a button that displays the `<FormComponent></FormComponent>` which is what I'm trying to display above

Comment: Which version of vuetify are you using?

Comment: @Hammerbot version 2.1.0, but I don't think it should matter, right?

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify globally registers all components by default when you do `Vue.use(Vuetify)`. This allows you to use the Vuetify components without explicitly registering them in your component:

*src/plugins/vuetify.js:*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({})
```

*src/main.js:*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  ...
})
```

To avoid code bloat (bundling unused components), Vuetify recommends using [`vuetify-loader` for treeshaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte):

> Keeping track of all the components you're using can be a real chore. The [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) alleviates this pain by automatically importing all the Vuetify components you use, where you use them. This will also make code-splitting more effective, as webpack will only load the components required for that chunk to be displayed.

You'd configure your project to use `vuetify-loader` like this:

*vue.config.js:*

```js
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ],
  }
}
```

[Vuetify 2.2.14 demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-grass-gljcu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: Before I had `vuetify` from './plugins/vuetify' like this:`new Vue(..., vuetify, ...)`. After I changed to `Vue.use(Vuetify)`, it still shows the same error:  `Unknown custom element: <v-text-field> - did you register the component correctly?`

Comment: Actually inside the plugins vuetify lib, there is `Vue.use(Vuetify);` already

Comment: I'm baffled as for why it works on your example, but not on my code...

Comment: @JMarkov You said `After I changed to Vue.use(Vuetify)`, which implies you weren't doing that before. The problem is likely in how you're initializing Vuetify. Please show that in your question.

Comment: But then I said that inside the vuetify plugin file there was that code!

Comment: Vuetify works correctly anywhere else. I tried adding `Vue.use(Vuetify);` directly instead of loading the plugin file that had it and nothing changed.

Comment: Can you show your initialization code in your question?

Comment: Ok, I put above. It was generated by vue cli and when I installed vuetify, the rest was also added automatically. I think the only stuff I changed was `data`

Comment: Init code looks fine. I guess we'll need a reproducible example to troubleshoot. Do you have a GitHub link?